# Derivative goes to $0$, then function goes to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**: Suppose $f$ is defined and differentiable for $x>0$, and $f'(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$. Put $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Prove that $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

**Source**: W. Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Chapter 5, exercise 5.

Comment: I presume you mean "*as* $x\to+\infty$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mean value theorem, we know that

$$f(x+1)-f(x)=g(x)=f'(t)$$

for some $t\in (x, x+1)$. Then, because $f'\rightarrow 0$, so does $g$.